# DevExpress: can devexpress shareable?

Tags: installation, devexpress, licensing

How it will work if I use an installer of **devExpress** legit copy from someone?

Will it be a Legit Version or a Trial version?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 11):

DevExpress license is based on a per-developer basis. Thus **each developer** that uses DevExpress products **must have their own license**.

To learn more see [Licensing - Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/licensingfaq.xml)

Comment: any one can share his installer???? i saw their website its redistrubuteable..

Comment: Redistributable means you can provide DevExpress' DLLs with your applications.